# Prove or disprove $C$ is a subset of $D$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a question posted by my lecturer, but so far no one have been able to solve it yet

Let $\Bbb R$ be the set of real numbers.

The sets $C$ and $D$ are defined as follows:

$C = \{(a,b) \mid a^2 + b^2< 1,(a,b) ∈ \Bbb R\times \Bbb R\}$

$D = \{(a,b) \mid 2ab < 1,(a,b) ∈\Bbb R\times \Bbb R\}$

Prove or disprove $C$ is a subset of $D$.

Comment: Does $(1/2, 0)$ belong to D?

Comment: @FernandoMartin Yes, it does.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff: Time to go to sleep, it seems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note $$(a-b)^2\geq 0$$

This is $$a^2-2ab+b^2\geq 0$$ or

$$a^2+b^2\geq 2ab$$

Suppose $(a,b)\in C$. Then $a^2+b^2<1$. But because of $(1)$, it must be $2ab\leq a^2+b^2<1$, so $(a,b)\in D$. All in all, $C\subseteq D$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is: take any point $\,\left(x\,,\,\frac{1}{2x}\right)\in D\,$ . We now show its distance from the origin is greater or equal than $\,1$ :

$$x^2+\frac{1}{4x^2}\geq 1\Longleftrightarrow(2x^2-1)^2\geq 0$$

Thus, the whole hyperbola $\,D\,$ is "outside" the circle  $\,C\,$ or at most intersects it in one point, which means that all the points in the circle are between the hyperbole and the axis and, thus, they belong to $\,D\,$

Answer (score 0):

Obviously  $2ab\le a^2+b^2 \forall a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ So $\forall (a,b)\in C,\implies (a,b)\in D$ and hence done
Edited: As for any $(a,b)\in C, \implies a^2+b^2<1\implies 2ab<1\implies (a,b)\in D$
$2ab\le a^2+b^2\iff 0\le a^2+b^2-2ab=(a-b)^2$ which is obvious as every square of a real number is always greater than or equal to $0$

Comment: I was reading something wrongly. I deleted the comment

Comment: is it really true that a x a + b x b is bigger than a x b + a x b for all real numbers?

Comment: yes, look at the edited part